# Help to identify unknown IC from Microchip

Tags: integrated-circuit

I am asking here hoping that someone may have experience identifying these kind of old chips. Googling the reference just shows some forums with people in same situation as me.

IC reference: 25072478 REV D
[image: 25072478 REV D]

This is an Opel LCD dashboard design from the mid 80s. So the chip should have been available at that time.

8 of the pins are connected to the main controller, which is a known part:
SAB80515
[image: SAB80515]

I am also trying to get at least a part of the board schematic.

Thank you.

EDIT 1: The chips connects this way, I have to check the other pins left blank at the moment.

[image: Schematic simplified]

Answer (score 1):

The small chip is probably a one off chip made for whoever manufactured this board. Your best best bet is examining what the pins connect to and analyzing what they may do. Since its a one off chip the chance of finding a datasheet is slim to none.

The big chip is a variation of the [Intel 8051](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_MCS-51) which is common in 80's car technology. The datasheet can be found [here](http://www.b-kainka.de/Daten/Mikros/d80515.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for answering, I found that the chip is listed in some online salers or similar webs but they don't provide the datasheet. I don't know if this chip would be based on a standard chip and then relabeled or maybe it is an independent development. I will update the original question showing the connections with the main controller.